# ASP.NET Identity creates 2 rows in user table for 1 user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an application in ASP.NET MVC C#. I have selected the Invididual user accounts options and installed the Identity package. I have configured the register and login functions in the AccountController to do some extra things. I added the ability to add a role when a users registers, seen with `UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, Student)`. I have also made it so that it automatically creates a new row in the User table to store the information.

**Register:**

```
        [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Student");  //Will automatically add users as students once registered
                Service.IService Service = new Service.Service();
                Data.User newUser = new Data.User
                {
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    Username = model.Name,
                    Email = model.Email
                };  //Will insert a new row in the User class with the attributes listed
                Service.AddUser(newUser);
                Session.Add("UserId", user.Id);  //Adds User to the session
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("AddUser", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Login:**

```
       [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                Service.IService Service =
                    new Service.Service();
                Data.User loginUser = Service.GetUserEmail(model.Email);
                Session.Add("UserId", loginUser.UserId); 
                var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
                    new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
                IList<string> roles = um.GetRoles(loginUser.UserId);
                Session.Add("Roles", roles);
                return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "Home", new { id = loginUser.UserId });
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

When I log out of the account and try to log back in, I get this error `System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.` which points to the fact that it cannot retrieve the User Id when it runs the action GetUserEmail.

**GetUserEmail:**

```
        public User GetUserEmail(string email, MyContext context) //Retrieves user information by querying both tables to find matching rows
    {
        IQueryable<User> user = from u in context.Users where u.Email == email select u;
        return user.ToList().First();
    }
```

When I look into the User table, there are 2 rows for every user. 1 row contains the UserId that they created when signing up and then another row with the hash user Id created from Identity. This is where it is breaking, it is trying to retrieve the wrong user ID. I have an application that runs perfectly and only inserts 1 row into the User table, why is this occuring?

[image]

Comment: You already created the user with UserManager ***CreateAsync*** method then why you're again adding a user with ***Service.AddUser(newUser)***?

Answer (score 2):

In the `Register` action, this line creates a user:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Then below you are inserting a user again:

```
Service.AddUser(newUser);
```

If you would like to update the user after it is inserted into the database, assuming you are using `Entity Framework`, then you should be able to use `context.Update(user);` instead creating a `newUser` object and adding that. Then call `context.SaveChangesAsync();`

If it is not Entity Framework, and a custom service with your own methods for reading and writing to a database, then just fetch the User object from the database, update the values, and call your update method.